# Remove tags from div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a simple code in Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

webpage = urllib2.urlopen('http://fakepage.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)

for anchor in soup.find_all("div", id="description"):
    print anchor
```

I almost get what I want, but between `<div id=description>` and `</div>` I get lots of tags:

```html
<div id="description"><div class="t"><p>some text to show <br><br> lots of <b> useless</b> tags </br></br></p></div></div>
```

I would like to get only text (not tags) that is between `<div id=description>` and `</div>` to count the words. 
Is there any function in BeautifulSoup that can help me?

Comment: your title has  `didv` instead of `div`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`element.get_text()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to get *just* the text:

```
for anchor in soup.find_all("div", id="description"):
    print anchor.get_text()
```

You can pass in `strip=True` to remove extra whitespace, and the first argument is used to join the stripped strings:

```
for anchor in soup.find_all("div", id="description"):
    print anchor.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample = '''\
... <div id="description"><div class="t"><p>some text to show <br><br> lots of <b> useless</b> tags </br></br></p></div></div>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> for anchor in soup.find_all("div", id="description"):
...     print anchor.get_text()
... 
some text to show  lots of  useless tags 
>>> for anchor in soup.find_all("div", id="description"):
...     print anchor.get_text(' ', strip=True)
... 
some text to show lots of useless tags
```